# Issues with setting up Magento from command line tool

Tags: magento

Please help me to setup magento via command line tool. Here are the errors:

```
Xpress@Xpress-PC /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/magento2 
$ ./mage mage-setup
Running initial setup...
./mage: line 50: exec: php: not found
./mage: line 50: exec: php: not found
./mage: line 50: exec: php: not found
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it cannot find the PHP command. This is most probably because of the missing path to your PHP directory. As you are using cygdrive on windows this is more probable. Try to add this line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/c/xampp/php
```

in the bash.bashrc file (you can find it inside the folder where you installed cygwin. Should be here: C:\cygwin64\etc\bash.bashrc); this code will add the PHP (installed in: C:\xampp\php)  to your path

Comment: I'm getting this message now

Comment: Xpress@Xpress-PC /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/magento
$ ./mage
Could not open input file: /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/magento/downloader/mage.php

Xpress@Xpress-PC /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/magento
$ ./mage mage-setup
Running initial setup...
Could not open input file: /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/magento/downloader/mage.php
Could not open input file: /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/magento/downloader/mage.php
Could not open input file: /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/magento/downloader/mage.php