# CakePHP bake console bake all error line 40: exec: php: not found

Tags: cakephp-bake, cakephp-2.7

am new to CakePHP 2.7.3 and running Linux Mint 17. I tried out the bake command after creating my database but each time i run  `./projects/school/app/Console/cake bake all`  I get the error message`../lib/Cake/Console/cake: line 40: exec: php: not found`. I have tried making the cake file in `../app/Console` executable but i still get the error message. Kindly assist

Comment: Have you searched for [similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32647044/cakephp-3-server-php-not-found) with [similar error messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795525/issues-with-setting-up-magento-from-command-line-tool) already? If so and you couldn't find a solution please extend your question and give more information what you have tried so far...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:
apt-get install php5-cli